# Is it possible to create and preview a table using Visual Studio Code Markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, commonmark

I am using Visual Studio Code to write some notes using [its Markdown support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown). I would like to add some tables, but I can't find a way to do it. It seems that Visual Studio Code implements [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) which does not include tables in the specification.

I know that GitHub flavoured Markdown has [a table extension](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-) which provides this feature and there are a couple of table formatter Visual Studio Code extensions ([here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=josa.markdown-table-formatter) and [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shuworks.vscode-table-formatter)), but they just layout the text nicely. I would like to a table to show up in the preview pane.

Any suggestions for how to achieve some tables in Visual Studio Code Markdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original [Markdown rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown's syntax, you simply
>   use HTML itself. There's no need to preface it or delimit it to
>   indicate that you're switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the
>   tags.
>
> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements -- e.g.
>   `<div>`, `<table>`, `<pre>`, `<p>`, etc. -- must be separated from
>   surrounding content by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the
>   block should not be indented with tabs or spaces. Markdown is smart
>   enough not to add extra (unwanted) `<p>` tags around HTML block-level
>   tags.
>
> For example, to add an HTML table to a Markdown article:
>
> ```
> This is a regular paragraph.
>
> <table>
>     <tr>
>         <td>Foo</td>
>     </tr>
> </table>
>
> This is another regular paragraph.
> ```
>
> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within
>   block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can't use Markdown-style `*emphasis*`
>   inside an HTML block.

Comment: I guess it's not that pretty, but it works - thanks.

Answer (score 21):

You can now do something like this:

```
| Letter | Digit | Character |
| :----: | :---: | :-------: |
| a      | 4     | $         |
|        | 365   | (         |
| b      |       | ^         |
```

"Empty" cells must have at least one space in them.  This will display in vscode's markdown preview as:

[image: markdown table demo in vscode preview]